# Android: How to position an image slightly outside of a view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-image

I wish to position an image slightly outside of a linear layout in my android application. It may be eaiser if I use an image to explain.
[image: Example image explaining my question]

In the above image I have tried to show the three views that would be involved.

1. Grey Background - A Linear layout.
2. White "page" - A Linear layout.
3. Red "clip" - The image that I wish to position.

As you can see from the image my aim is to position the clip as if it is a "paper clip", firstly is it possible to create the above layout in android xml. IF it is possible could someone please point me in the right direction (preferably with an explained example of code).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, just use a `FrameLayout`.

Something like:

```
<FrameLayout>
    <View android:id="@+id/paper" android:marginLeft="10dp"/>
    <View android:id="@+id/paperclip"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer it gave me just what I needed quickly. However to both the other answers (Simon and Dan S) thank you also. I have added the webpage that Simon linked to my reading list.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible, one possible way of doing this is to overlay a layout on top of the other. I would suggest putting your existing `LinearLayout` inside a `RelativeLayout` and putting your "paperclip" in an `ImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a FrameLayout, using margin and padding to position the paper clip as you need. The key to understanding FrameLayouts is to understand that every view you add to one anchors to the top left corner.  You are going to have to cut some code to deal with any possible resolution, assuming that you want to position the clip arbitrarily - otherwise, you could simply use a fixed number of DIPs margin to position as you need.

http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-1-layouts